# unexpected results when automatically importing local vs global modules - using bytepath lua love2d tutorial

Tags: module, lua, local, require, love2d

I'm going through the BYTEPATH tutorial and it's asking me to work out a function that automatically imports my module files.  After searching and fiddling, I have something that works.  Just one weird thing I can't figure out.

Any global modules get their class-table-object imported in camelcase, just like the in the actual file.  (The modules all extend rsi's class module as 'Obect')  However local modules all come in as lowercase just like the filename.

This is what I mean:

[image]
[image]

Any idea why this is happening?  Ideally, I'd like them to come in to match the class/table style in camelcase.  But mostly, I'd like to understand what is going on here.

**main.lua**

```
--! file: main.lua

Object = require "libraries.classic"

local object_files = {}
local c1, h1

function string:split( inSplitPattern )
    local outResults = {}
    local theStart = 1
    local theSplitStart, theSplitEnd = string.find( self, inSplitPattern, theStart )
    while theSplitStart do
        table.insert( outResults, string.sub( self, theStart, theSplitStart-1 ) )
        theStart = theSplitEnd + 1
        theSplitStart, theSplitEnd = string.find( self, inSplitPattern, theStart )
    end
    table.insert( outResults, string.sub( self, theStart ) )
    return outResults
end

function love.keypressed(key, u)
   --Debug
   if key == "rctrl" then
      debug.debug()
   end
end

function recursiveEnumerate(folder, file_list)
    local filesTable = love.filesystem.getDirectoryItems(folder)
    for i,v in ipairs(filesTable) do
        local file = folder .. '/' .. v
        if love.filesystem.getInfo(file, 'file') then
            table.insert(file_list, file)
        elseif love.filesystem.getInfo(file, 'directory') then
            recursiveEnumerate(file, file_list)
        end
    end
end

function requireFiles(files)
  for _,filepath in ipairs(files) do
    local filepath = filepath:sub(1, -5)
    -- using a split function because lua doesn't have one built-in
    local parts = filepath:split("/")
    local class = parts[#parts]
    _G[class] = require(filepath)
  end
end

function love.load()
   recursiveEnumerate('objects', object_files)
   requireFiles(object_files)
   image = love.graphics.newImage('image.png')
   c1 = Circle(400, 300, 50)
   hc1 = HyperCircle(400, 300, 50, 50, 50)
end

function love.update(dt)
    c1:update(dt)
    hc1:update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
    for i,v in ipairs(object_files) do
        love.graphics.print(object_files[i], 20, 20 + (i * 10))
    end
    c1:draw()
    hc1:draw()
end
```

**circle.lua (global, comes in like camelcase class/table object)**

```
Circle = Object:extend()    
function Circle:new(x, y, radius)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.radius = radius
    self.creation_time = love.timer.getTime()
end    
function Circle:update(dt)        
end    
function Circle:draw()
    love.graphics.circle('fill', self.x, self.y, self.radius)
end
```

**hypercircle.lua (global, comes in camelcase like class/table object)**

```
HyperCircle = Circle:extend()
local distance
local widthy
function HyperCircle:new(x, y, radius, outer_radius_distance, line_width)
    HyperCircle.super.new(self, x, y)
    self.radius = radius
    self.outer_radius = self.radius + outer_radius_distance
    self.line_width = line_width
    distance = self.outer_radius
    widthy = self.line_width
end
function HyperCircle:update(dt)
    self.outer_radius = love.math.random(self.radius, distance + 200)
    self.line_width = love.math.random(1, widthy)
end
function HyperCircle:draw()
    love.graphics.setLineWidth(self.line_width)
    love.graphics.circle('line', self.x, self.y, self.outer_radius)
end
```

**testclass.lua (local, comes in lowercase like file)**

```
local TestClass = Object:extend()   
function TestClass:new()    
end    
function TestClass:update()        
end    
function TestClass:draw()      
end    
return TestClass
```

Comment: Hint: Do the modules that use globals come in just as CamelCase, or do they come in both as CamelCase and as lowercase?

Comment: Possibly an OS issue, due to `love.filesystem.getInfo()` not differentiating between capitalized items.

Comment: @Doyousketch2 Not likely.

Comment: Or an alternate version of `testclass.bak`.  Your `filepath:sub(1, -5)` just truncates extension without actually determining what it is.

Answer (score 1):

A "local" module (which doesn't set a global variable) returns only a Lua value.  It doesn't return the name of the local variable holding the value.
The local variable name `TestClass` is visible only inside the module where it was defined.  So, the "outer world" has to use the filename instead.